# Combinations of a pattern satisfying given constraints

Tags: algorithm, sorting, combinations

Pattern consisting of 1s and 0s are given. It's always 7 bits and 3 bits are 1s and 4 bits are 0s

example - 1100010

Constraint is to consider 2 0s at once and substitute them with 1s. I need to find all such possible combinations.

So far what I thought was, finding the indexes of 0s and running a for loop to select 2 indexes at each run and get the output.

**Example -**

given pattern - 1100010

required outputs -1111010, 1110110, 1110011, 1101110, 1101011, 1100111

I can do this in an exhaustive manner. Any suggestion to do this in a more optimized manner will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem boils down to finding all combinations of 4 choose 2. Your idea of getting the indices of zeros is a good starting place.

For the example given, `1100010`, we have the following:

```
1 1 0 0 0 1 0
| | | | | | |
V V V V V V V 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   // indices here assuming base 0
```

Thus our vector of zero indices is `{2, 3, 4, 6}`.

Now, we can generate all combinations of our zero index vector choose 2 (there are several great algorithms readily available on SO or the web) and make the appropriate substitutions to generate our output.

Pseudocode:

```
inputVec = {1,1,0,0,0,1,0}
zeroIndex = {}

for i in 0 to (length(inputVec) - 1)
    if (inputVec[i] == 0)
        zeroIndex.push_back(i)     // zeroIndex = {2, 3, 4, 6} for the given example

// initialize output vector to the input vector
newOutput = inputVec
myCombos = generateCombos(zeroIndex, 2) // matrix of combinations with 2 columns

for i in 0 to (length(myCombos) - 1) {
    newOutput[myCombos[i, 0]] = 1
    newOutput[myCombos[i, 1]] = 1
    print(newOutput)

    // reset output vector
    newOutput = inputVec
}
```

In the algorithm above, `generateCombos` would output the following:

```
     [,0] [,1]
[0,]    2    3
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    2    6
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    3    6
[5,]    4    6
```

The algorithm outlined extends to the general case where the input vector is of any length and has an arbitrary number of 0's and 1's.

Comment: Thank you very much @JosephWood

Comment: @Paddy3118 I understood your code aswell. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find where your four zeroes in  your input are and number their bit positions.
2. Ignoring the positions of the zeroes in the input for a while, you have four zeroes that will turn into two zeroes and two ones.
3. Find the unique set of permutations of '0011' in order.
4. For each perm: replace the ones and zeroes, preserving order, into the original positions of just the zeroes in the original number to produce one of the outputs.

Something like:

```python
from itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint as pp

unique_perms = set(permutations('0011'))

num = input('number: ').strip()  # Keep as text
for perm in unique_perms:
    out = []
    p = list(perm)
    for bit in num:
        out.append(bit if bit == '1' else p.pop())
    print('->', ''.join(out))
```

Sample run:

```
number: 1100010
-> 1111010
-> 1101110
-> 1110110
-> 1100111
-> 1110011
-> 1101011
```

Comment: Won’t this add unnecessary overhead? I know for the particular example this won’t matter, but as a matter of general best programming practices, this algorithm scales poorly. For example imagine we had just 20 zeros we had to replace with say 5 ones. This algorithm would have to sift through `factorial(20)` permutations whereas a combination approach only has to deal with a much more manageable 20 choose 5 results.

Comment: No.  Address the problem you have. What part of 7 bits, with 4 zeroes was not addressed? 

If you are looking for a cute aphorism try **"You ain't gonna need it"**

Comment: ... or *"Good enough is perfect"*

Comment: I see what you’re saying and don’t get me wrong, I’m not trying to be disrespectful. It’s just I can’t tell you how many times phrases like *”Good enough is perfect”* have burned not just me personally, but my entire department. We have spent months on cleaning up code that was *good enough* at the time, when this could have been avoided with a small investment in code quality upfront. I could also see your point if what you were implementing is vastly more simple than the *best* method, but actually your method requires additional layers of complexity via knowledge of `set`.

Comment: @JosephWood Hi, sorry about any perceived harshness of tone. Because there are repetitions in the items being permuted, you get repeated perms. The call to set is used to remove those repetitions. Sets are a native Python data structure with an interface that should be easier than dicts to learn. As for assigning which is *best*, that is up to the person with the original problem. This calculates the answers needed, displays them, and all in negligible time and memory. It seems performant enough to work for *all* possible 7 bit inputs in a short while.